# Meeting time Random Walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

I am interesting to calculate a *meeting time* of two nodes which move according to continuous time random walk in 2D space.

Comment: What makes you think they will meet with more than zero probability?

Comment: Nothing makes me think that, but still, even if the probability is zero I want to know how to calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume with "continuous time random walk" you mean a brownian motion.

Check [Theorem 3.3 in this lecture notes](https://www.math-berlin.de/images/stories/lecnotes_moerters.pdf) where it's shown that two independent brownian motions intersect iff the dimension is less or equal then 3.

So, in 2D space they intersect almost surely…